# how to merge multiple rows into single in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, hive

this is my data:
[image]

id  segment country product status  month   year

83916512    Government  Null    Null    Null    Null    2014
83916512    Null    Germany Null    Null    Null    2014
83916512    Null    Null     Carretera  Null    Null    2014
83916512    Null    Null    Null     completed Null 2014
83916512    Null    Null    Null    Null     June   2014
83916512    Null    Null    Null    Null    Null    2014

i want below output
[image]

can anybody help me out to achieve this please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following SQL Select

```
select
    id,
    MAX(segment) as segment,
    MAX(country) as country,
    MAX(product) as product,
    MAX(status) as status,
    MAX(month) as month,
    MAX(year) as year
from tbl
group by id
```

Comment: hey @Eralper your solution worked.I was wandering how MAX function worked for string data type.

Comment: @Pikun95 . . . The same way it works for any data type.  It returns the maximum value.

Comment: Since, compared values is NULL in your case, MAX() here only brings the not null value. By the way this is a technique I use frequently while pivoting data or displaying data in multiple columns. Here is an example case http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/display-data-in-multiple-columns-in-sql.aspx where I display single column data in 4 or 5 column format

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id
    ,COALESCE(segment) AS segment
    ,COALESCE(country) AS country
    ,COALESCE(product) AS product
    ,COALESCE(STATUS) AS STATUS
    ,COALESCE(month) AS month
    ,COALESCE(year) AS year
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation to your code as code only as answer is not suggested and promoted by this site. Also the code is formatted wrongly.